# lodash throttling - Function not called when binded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have a div and when scrolling this particular div i want to fire a certain function. To limit the number of functions firing when scrolling, i have used `lodash throttling feature`. But for some reason binding the function like below prevents the events to be passed to the function.

This is how i've used throttle feature

```
this.listenScrollEvent = _.throttle(this.onWidgetScroll, 2000).bind(this);
```

My div looks something like below

```
    <div
        id={this.props.isInfiniteScoll ? 'infinite' : ''}
        onScroll={this.listenScrollEvent}

        {this.renderCards()}
    </div>
```

And finally the function

```
listenScrollEvent(e) {
   this.onWidgetScroll(e);
}
```

I have tried like this as well

```
onScroll={(e) => this.listenScrollEvent(e)}
```

Comment: I suppose you mean tot use `_.throttle(this.onWidgetScroll.bind(this), 2000)`?

Comment: Also, I'm not too sure if you really need to bind lexical this to the function. `_.throttle(this.onWidgetScroll, 2000)` might suffice, actually.